# What is the difference between $\int_{I}f\phi=0$ and $\int_{I}f\phi’=0$

Tags: real-analysis

It is known that suppose $f\in L^1(I)$, then 
if $\int_{I}f\phi=0$ for any $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(I)$, then $f=0$. It is stated in Brezis’s book that if  $\int_{I}f\phi’=0$ then $f$ is constant. My question is why we have these two different statements, can we write every  $\phi$ as the derivative of another infinite differentiable function with compact support so as to make the second statement equivalent to the first one

Comment: In the second statement, use integration by parts to get $\int_I f'\phi = 0$, which will imply $f' = 0$ by the first statement. Also, take care that the word here is really *every*, not *any*. You need $\int_I f\phi = 0$ for *every* such $\phi$.

Answer (score 3):

Actually $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(I)$ can be written as $\psi'$ for some $C^\infty_0(I)$ if and only if $\int_I \varphi =0$ (of course $\varphi = \psi'$ for some $\psi \in C^\infty(I)$). That can be shown by fundamental theorem of calculus.